# PHP - Predis Connection Timeout

Tags: php, redis, predis

I have absolutely no idea what's going on. I'm trying to connect to a Redis server and I can connect fine using redis-cli but using Predis I get the first error. If I use redis-cli everything is fine. I am 100% sure the passwords and IPs are correct. The firewall is turned off on the server.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Predis\Connection\ConnectionException: Connection timed out [tcp://[server ip]:6379] in /path/to/.../vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:155
Stack trace:
#0 path/to/.../vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(128): Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection->onConnectionError('Connection time...', 110)
#1 path/to/.../vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(178): Predis\Connection\StreamConnection->createStreamSocket(Object(Predis\Connection\Parameters), 'tcp://[server ip]...', 4)
#2 path/to/.../vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(100): Predis\Connection\StreamConnection->tcpStreamInitializer(Object(Predis\Connection\Parameters))
#3 path/to/.../vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(81): Predis\Connection\StreamConnection->createResource()
#4 path/to/.../vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php on line 155
```

This is the response from redis-cli:

```
$ redis-cli -h [server ip]
[server ip]:6379> AUTH [redis password]
OK
[server ip]:6379> PING
PONG
[server ip]:6379>
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php

include '../../vendor/autoload.php';

function sendMessage($tube, $msg) {
    $client = new Predis\Client(array(
        "scheme" => "tcp",
        //"host" => "127.0.0.1",
        "host" => "[server ip]",
        "port" => 6379
    ), array(
        "parameters" => [
            "password" => "[redis password]"
        ]
    ));

    $client->rpush($tube, $msg);
}

sendMessage('test', "test");

?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I found the problem. The firewall on the website was blocking the outgoing connection.